# Using JSON_TABLE to fetch a nested JSON array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, sql-update, mysql-json

I have a Json array while looks as below

```
[{"keyId": "aded5b0107bb5a936604bcb6f", "keyNames": ["abc1, abc2"], "keyDesc": "test"}]
```

I am using JSON_TABLE to fetch all the values and I have written the following query:

```
SELECT j.keyId, j.keyNames, j.keyDesc
FROM table t, JSON_TABLE(value, '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS(
      keyId TEXT PATH '$.keyId' 
      keyNames TEXT PATH '$.keyNames',
      keyDesc TEXT PATH '$.keyDesc')
    ) AS j;
```

I am getting following output:

```
keyId                        keyNames   keyDesc
aded5b0107bb5a936604bcb6f    NULL       test
```

How to modify the query so as to get the values `"abc1, abc2"` for `keyNames` instead of `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need NEStED PATH for that as it is a  new array

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t
>     ( `value` TEXT)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO t
>     ( `value`)
> VALUES
>     ('[{"keyId": "aded5b0107bb5a936604bcb6f", "keyNames": ["abc1, abc2"], "keyDesc": "test"}]')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  
> j.keyId, j.keyNames,  j.keyDesc
>
> FROM t, JSON_TABLE(value, '$[*]' 
>     COLUMNS(
>       keyId TEXT PATH '$.keyId' 
>       ,NESTED PATH '$.keyNames[*]' COLUMNS (keyNames varchar(10) PATH '$')
>      , keyDesc TEXT PATH '$.keyDesc'
> )
>     ) AS j;
> ```

> ```
> keyId                     | keyNames   | keyDesc
> :------------------------ | :--------- | :------
> aded5b0107bb5a936604bcb6f | abc1, abc2 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a815b071206ad9105fd128ce6fbfe9f)*

Comment: I am still getting `NULL` for `keyNames`, This may be because `NESTED PATH` `keyNames` is not having any column `keyNames`. can you please check?

Comment: as you see in the fiddle i copied your json correctly so you can't get NULL else you have an error, please make a fiddle with your result

Comment: My data is exactly the same as your fiddle but I am still getting `NULL`. This is strange and not sure what is missing here

Comment: Changing `varchar(10)` to `varchar(50)` has resolved the issue. However, I am two rows here. One for `abc1` and other for `abc2`

Comment: then you don't have the same data see the double quotes around the hokle which makes a single string. Still the question is resoved

Comment: I believe it should be a small change to combine the two rows into a single row. can you please suggest what change is required here?